# How to catch @Input value change

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a component with this input:

```
@Input() list: Array<string>
```

How can I catch when parent component changes this input value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement [OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html)

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
  console.log(changes);
}
```

`ngOnChanges` is only called when the value was changed from the outside through Angular binding.

If you want to execute code when it is changed by other means you can also make a getter/setter like

```
_list:Array<string>;
@Input()
set input(newVal:Array<string>) {
  this._list = newVal;
  doSomething();
}

get input()Array<string> {
  return this._list;
}
```

This will not cover changes that are made to the same array, only when another array is assigned to `_list`.

Answer (score 5):

You could implement the `ngDoCheck` to manually detect when there are updates into the array (adding and / or removing). By defaut Angular2 doesn't detect this case since it works on references and not on content.

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeComponent implements DoCheck {
  @Input() list: Array<string>;

  constructor(private differ:KeyValueDiffer) {
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    var changes = this.differ.diff(this.list);
    if (changes) {
      changes.forEachAddedItem(r => {
        // element added in the input array
      });
      changes.forEachRemovedItem(r => {
        // element removed in the input array
      });
  }
}
```

The `ngFor` directive relies on this mechanism.

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/LVQqpjbLENZ7AZ2a6OTt?p=preview.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "changes" -- are you assigning a new array for each change (i.e., following the immutable pattern), or are you manipulating the same array (i.e., manipulating the elements of a single array)?

For the immutable case, use lifecycle hook `OnChanges` (Günter's answer), otherwise use `DoCheck` (Thierry's answer).  Note that `ngDoCheck()` is called every time change detection runs, so only use it if you have to.

The Lifecycle Hooks dev guide covers these cases pretty well – [OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges), [DoCheck](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck) – although they don't show you how to use the [`IterableDiffer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/IterableDiffer-interface.html) with DoCheck like Thierry's answer.